# Error: Package oracle.jdbc.pool does not exist

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle12c

I am trying to implement JDBC in Oracle 12c, but I am running into trouble. In the class, test.java, I have the three following import statements:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource;
```

However, when I attempt to compile the class, I get the following error:

```
error: package oracle.jdbc.pool does not exist
```

What can I do to get this program to successfully compile and continue to implement JDBC?

Comment: Did you add the Oracle JDBC driver to your classpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the required package on the classpath. It seems to be failing because it cannot find the package there.